# Three colums, 2 width depends on inside elements and the middle depends on other two

Tags: html, css, variables, width, multiple-columns

i need a center div "fill" the remaining space left by the other two.
1. The left and right colum´s width depends on the number of elements inside them.
2. The left must be at left, the right must be at right.
3. The center has 4 elements which they width depends on the parent width (#center width)
4. The center width must fill the remaining space.
Thanks!!

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="elementInLeft"></div>
        <div class="elementInLeft"></div>
        <div class="elementInLeft"></div>
        <div class="elementInLeft"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        <div class="elementInCenter">1</div>
        <div class="elementInCenter">2</div>
        <div class="elementInCenter">3</div>
        <div class="elementInCenter">4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="elementInRight"></div>
        <div class="elementInRight"></div>
        <div class="elementInRight"></div>
        <div class="elementInRight"></div>
        <div class="elementInRight"></div>
        <div class="elementInRight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    #container
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #left
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .elementInLeft
    {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        background: #F00;
        float: left;
    }
    #center
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .elementInCenter
    {
        width: 25%;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        background: #0F0;
    }
    #right
    {
        float: right;
    }
    .elementInRight
    {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        background: #00F;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
    #container {
      display: flex;
    }
    .elementInLeft {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background: #F00;
      float: left;
    }
    #center {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
    }
    .elementInCenter {
      height: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      flex: 1;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      background: #0F0;
    }
    .elementInRight {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background: #00F;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="elementInLeft"></div>
    <div class="elementInLeft"></div>
    <div class="elementInLeft"></div>
    <div class="elementInLeft"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <div class="elementInCenter">1</div>
    <div class="elementInCenter">2</div>
    <div class="elementInCenter">3</div>
    <div class="elementInCenter">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="elementInRight"></div>
    <div class="elementInRight"></div>
    <div class="elementInRight"></div>
    <div class="elementInRight"></div>
    <div class="elementInRight"></div>
    <div class="elementInRight"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```